# Find time difference between current time and a string

Tags: javascript, time

how am I able to `parse` a time string in the following format `12:10AM` and then get javascript to find the time difference between that time and the current time

Comment: Will it be always in that format HH:MMXM?

Comment: "that date" or "that time" (the difference)? Also there are 2 differences... if the current time is 12.00AM the difference may be either 10mins or 23hours and 50mins.

Comment: yes it will be in the HH:MMXM format

Answer (score 1):

Use `momentjs`. It can parse, manipulate, and display dates in javascript. It's incredible and has wide variety of parse formats and manipulations.

If you don't find the format available, just use Regex and extract the time components and pass them to momentjs. Then you can find the time difference and format the difference in displayable format also.

For more info on momentjs: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript regular expressions:

var dateParseRe = /(\d\d):(\d\d)(\w\w)/g;
dateParse.exec("12:10AM");

Comment: This only answers part of the question. And always beware with using regex when you don't need it.. This would also match 99:99XZ as being a time.